# Issue with ShadcnUI components causing input zoom on iPhone

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm encountering a problem with the ShadcnUI components specifically on iPhone devices where the input zooms in when opening the page on mobile. This issue seems to affect the input behavior, particularly when the page is viewed on an iPhone.

I've attempted to resolve this by including the following meta tag in the HTML:

Sure, I can help you craft a question for Stack Overflow regarding the issue you're facing with the ShadcnUI components on iPhone causing zooming in the input window. Here's a suggested template:

Title: Issue with ShadcnUI components causing input zoom on iPhone

Description:

I'm encountering a problem with the ShadcnUI components specifically on iPhone devices where the input zooms in when opening the page on mobile. This issue seems to affect the input behavior, particularly when the page is viewed on an iPhone.

I've attempted to resolve this by including the following meta tag in the HTML:

html
Copy code

However, this hasn't resolved the problem.

To demonstrate the issue, you can visit the following example on the ShadcnUI documentation page: Responsive Dialog at bottom

When scrolling to the bottom of the page on an iPhone, the input zooms in unexpectedly.

Could anyone provide insight into why this behavior is occurring and suggest possible solutions or workarounds?

Steps to reproduce:

Visit the Responsive Dialog at bottom example page on an iPhone.
Scroll to the bottom of the page where the input is located.
Observe the input zooming in unexpectedly.
Expected behavior:

The input should not zoom in when scrolling on the page.

Additional information:

Device: iPhone (specify model if necessary)
Browser: Safari (specify version if necessary)
ShadcnUI version: (if known)
Any other relevant details or attempts to resolve the issue.
Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Chat gpt question? See how to create a [minimal reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `"Sure, I can help you craft a question for Stack Overflow regarding the issue you're facing"`!

Comment: Have you read the AI response?

Comment: Even your AI helper knows that you need to add extra information - which you don't seem to have realised. Just dumping an AI generated question here is unlikely to go down well given SO's current policy on AI generated content. There are a lot of people on here willing to help you but I strongly suggest you write the question yourself and include enough code for us to  be able to help. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask